# Refresh single page PHP element using button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a single page quote generator, it works by holding the quotes in a 2D array and generating a random number to pull from the matching value in the array using PHP every time that the page is refreshed, I want to change this and make it so that only the element is changed when you press a button, reducing the http requests to the server.

I have tried various "onClick" methods but they never seem to work, I'm assuming that this is something that I should use Javascript (Or any js libraries) for. The function that I want to run when the button is pressed is this:

```
  <?php 
    $max = max(array_map('count', $arrCSV));
    $num = rand(0,$max);
    $quote = $arrCSV[0][$num] . "." ;
    echo $quote;
  ?>
```

Any help is much, much appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged this with jQuery, show us what you've tried so far

Comment: PaulDixon - I'm not really too sure at all, and just thinking jQuery might be helpful in this case, as its the library I'm most familiar with. As Kameleon said though, ajax is probably the way to do this.

Comment: You can still use AJAX via jQuery (actually, it's the very same approach; although a bit more... user-friendly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like, @Dr.Kameleon, this cannot be done with PHP alone.

Using jQuery, you can reload an element like this

```
$("#yourdiv").load("the/page/from/where/it/should/be/updated.php");
```

Attach it to the click event of the button

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#yourdiv").load("the/page/from/where/it/should/be/updated.php"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery's load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) could do miracles there.

Answer (score 2):

Here some working example.

Create html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS-ajax-PHP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      // Let's use jQuery library:

      $(document).ready(function() {
        // get element with id refresh, on click do function...
        $('#refresh').click(function(evt){
          // get element with id report, load content to element
          $('#report').load('/time.php');
          evt.preventDefault();
        })
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="refresh">Обновить</button>

    <div id="report">        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and php file `time.php`:

```
<?php
  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Enjoy.